# improvement setters and methods that i need to fill fields

Tags: java, design-patterns, setter, getter

i have a model with multiple fields, therefore, i have setters and getters methods, then,i need to fill this fields with zeros o blank spaces to the left, i already have a method for this but i will need to call it on every setter, how can i improve this and does not have a lot of duplicate code?

here is the example:

```
public String rellenarStringConEspaciosEnBlanco(String cadenaARellenar, int tamanoACumplir,
        int tamanoCadenaARellenar) {
    int size = tamanoACumplir - tamanoCadenaARellenar;
    if(size>0) {
        String formato = "%-" + size + "s";
        String rellenar = String.format(formato, " ");
        cadenaARellenar = cadenaARellenar + rellenar;
        return cadenaARellenar;
    }
    return cadenaARellenar;
```

Comment: Have you heard of loops

Comment: Just include it in the setter itself.

Comment: If you need to set each field then you need to call each setter there is no way around it except for using Reflection but you will need to ask yourself if it's worth all the work to take that route.

Comment: the loops is not the solution, yes i need to call each setter, but do i need to implements this code on each setter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didnt have to modify the DTO, the solution was not modify the DTO it was to create a new method on the class i was calling the setters, heres the code

```
detailRecord.setReferenceOne(rellenarCadena(datosExcelParaProcesar.getField("Referencia1"),detailRecord.getLengthReference1()));
```

and rellenar cadena is

```
    public String rellenarCadena(String cadenaParaRellenar, int sizeCadenaTotal){
    int size = sizeCadenaTotal-cadenaParaRellenar.length();
    if(size>0){
        String formato = "%-" + size + "s";
        String rellenar = String.format(formato, " ");
        cadenaParaRellenar = rellenar+cadenaParaRellenar;
    }
    return cadenaParaRellenar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have something like this

```
class Foo {
    String var1;
    String var2;

    void setVar1(String var1) {
        this.var1 = var1;
    }

    void setVar2(String var2) {
        this.var2 = var2;
    }
}
```

maybe you can add a constructor to initialize the object with spaces like this

```
class Foo {
    String var1;
    String var2;

    public Foo(String var1, String var2) {
        this.var1 = var1;
        this.var2 = var2;
    }

    void setVar1(String var1) {
        this.var1 = var1;
    }

    void setVar2(String var2) {
        this.var2 = var2;
    }
}
```

then you can do

```
Foo foo = new Foo(
    rellenarStringConEspaciosEnBlanco("A chain", 7, 1),
    rellenarStringConEspaciosEnBlanco("A chain", 7, 1)
);
```